# Asymptotic expansion of $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}{\frac{e^{-xt}}{\sqrt{t(x-t)}}}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

can you help, I want to find an asymptotic expansion of the function $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}{\frac{e^{-xt}}{\sqrt{t(x-t)}}}dt$
Thanks in advance

Comment: As $x$ tends to ?

Comment: I want to make it at   $\infty$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**. One may observe that, by the change of variable $t=x u$, $dt=x du$,
$$
f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}{\frac{e^{-xt}}{\sqrt{t(x-t)}}}\:dt=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-x^2u}}{\sqrt{u(1-u)}}\:du
$$ then one may use the Taylor expansion, for $0<u<1$,
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{u(1-u)}}=u^{-1/2}\left(1+\frac{u}{2}+\frac{3 u^2}{8}+O(u^4) \right)
$$ yielding, as $x \to \infty$, 
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\int_{0}^{1}u^{-1/2}\left(1+\frac{u}{2}+\frac{3 u^2}{8}+O(u^4) \right)e^{-x^2u}du
\\\\f(x)&=\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{-1/2}\left(1+\frac{u}{2}+\frac{3 u^2}{8}+O(u^4) \right)e^{-x^2u}du\:-O(e^{-x^2})
\end{align}
$$ thus, as $x \to \infty$,

> $$
> f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}x+\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4x^3}+\frac{9\sqrt{\pi}}{32x^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^7}\right)
> $$

where we have used the standard integral representation of the gamma function,
$$
\Gamma(s) = \int_0^\infty u^{s-1} e^{-u}\, du,\qquad s>0.
$$ *Remark*. The preceding expansion can be known at *any order* since one knows a closed form of the Taylor series expansion of $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-u}}$, $|u|<1$.

This is the classic [Watson's lemma](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~gajjar/MATH44011/notes/44011_note2.pdf).

Comment: i did comprehen, why did you do an asymptotic expansion for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{u(1-u)}}$ at 0 and not at $\infty$?And what happens from line 6 to 7?

Comment: At $u=0$ not $u \to \infty$, since $0<u<1$, not to be confused with $x \to \infty$. We have $x \ne u$. From line 6 to 7, observe that $\int_{0}^{1}u^{k}e^{-x^2u}du$ is equal to $\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{k}e^{-x^2u}du-\int_{1}^{\infty}u^{k}e^{-x^2u}du$ and the latter integral is $O(e^{-x^2})$.

Comment: More intuitively, perhaps, since the exponential function decreases so rapidly when $x$ is large, almost all of the integral comes from the region where $u\approx0$.